# Unable to display the image through the result of CRUD operations in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i am working on hotel booking app , in this i want to display the image of a hotel, based on user entered location . In this if i am displaying all hotels , i am able to display an image , if i am trying to displaying an image through some CRUD operations, i am unable to display it. Here are my code snippets.

```
class Customer_details(models.Model):

Name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
Age = models.IntegerField()
Mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
Email = models.EmailField()
Address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Special_request = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name
```

hotel_rating_choices  = (
    ('1','1'),
    ('2','2'),
    ('3','3'),
    ('4','4'),
    ('5','5'),
    ('6','6'),
    ('7','7'),
)

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
Hotel_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
no_of_rooms = models.IntegerField()
rating = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=hotel_rating_choices, default=3)
hotel_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_images/')
uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Hotel_Name

class Hotel_image(models.Model):

hotel_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'hotel_images/')
hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.hotel
```

**Ignore the remaining models just concentrate on Hotel model .**

`**Below code snippet is my view regarding to query.**

```
def get_hotels_by_location(request):

location  = request.POST.get('location')
print(location)
location = location.lower()
result = Hotel.objects.values('Hotel_Name', 'rating', 'hotel_img').filter(location=location)
context = {'hotels': result, 'header': ['Hotel_Name',  'Rating', 'image'] }
return render(
    request,
    template_name='display_hotel_by_location.html',
    context=context
)
```

**And below is my django html template**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        {% for i in header %}
            <th>
                {{ i }}
            </th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for element in hotels %}
    <tr>
        {% with  i=0 %}
       {% for key, value in element.items %}

            {% if i == 2 %}
                <td><a href="{{ element.url }}"> <img src="{{ element.url }}" width = "300" height="300"></a> </td>
            {% endif %}
            <td>  {{ value }} </td>
            {% with j=i %}
                j=j+1
                i=j
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Hotel.objects.filter(location=location).values('Hotel_Name', 'rating', 'hotel_img')

Comment: My problem is not on that one , in displaying the image i was able to display successfully in Hotel.objects.all() , but not in Hotel.objects.filter(location=location).values('Hotel_Name', 'rating', 'hotel_img').

Comment: Please have  a look at html template, and give me a suggestion on how to display the image in above CRUD operation. How to change the value of a variable in html template?

Comment: I know my html template is wrong, please help me through right html template

Comment: Ok give me 5 min and i'll post one snippet for you

Comment: Sure , i will wait for you

Comment: Why you have Hotel_Img in Hotel class and Hotel_Image? each hotel will have 1 or multiple images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Hotel_image class to add related name at your foreign to use it further

```
class Hotel_image(models.Model):

hotel_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'hotel_images/')
hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hotel_images")
```

Clean up a bit your views, you dont really need use values in that case.

```
from .models import Hotel

def get_hotels_by_location(request):

    location  = request.POST.get('location').lower()
    result = Hotel.objects.filter(location=location)
    context = {'hotels': result, 'header': ['Hotel_Name',  'Rating', 'image'] }
    return render(
        request,
        template_name='display_hotel_by_location.html',
        context=context
    )
```

**HTML 1 - If you consuming the hotel_img from class Hotel use this one**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        {% for i in header %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for hotel in hotels %}
    <tr>
       {% if forloop.counter0 == 2 and hotel.hotel_img %}
           <td><a href="{{ hotel.hotel_img.url }}"> <img src="{{ hotel.hotel_img.url }}" width="300" height="300"></a> </td>
       {% endif %}
        <td>  {{ hotel.Hotel_Name }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**HTML 2 - If you using the class Hotel_image use like that**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        {% for i in header %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for hotel in hotels %}
    <tr>
       {% for img in hotel.hotel_images %}
           {% if img.hotel_img %}
               <td><a href="{{ img.hotel_img.url }}"> <img src="{{ img.hotel_img.url }}" width="300" height="300"></a> </td>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
        <td>  {{ hotel.Hotel_Name }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

More info about Django relations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

**You can use Template Tags** too to filter all images from your Hotel_Image
1 - Create one folder called **templatetag** and inside that one file inside it to be your templatetag inside your app folder

hotel/templatetags/hotel_templatetag.py

Inside the file put that code

```
from django import template
from .models import Hotel_image

register = template.Library()

def get_hotel_images(self):
    return Hotel_image.objects.filter(id=self.id)
```

You Html should be like that

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        {% for i in header %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for hotel in hotels %}
    <tr>
       {% for img in hotel|get_hotel_images %}
           {% if img.hotel_img %}
               <td><a href="{{ img.hotel_img.url }}"> <img src="{{ img.hotel_img.url }}" width="300" height="300"></a> </td>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
        <td>  {{ hotel.Hotel_Name }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

More info about templatetags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But there are two problems in it, Firstly the image is displaying on new row in the page rather than in the same row, Second one is the forloop.counter0 == 2 only working for one image , that is displaying one image , from next onwards the counter never reaches 2 , what if there are 10 hotels, How to display? please help me on this.

Comment: This is wrong logic of yours, 1 - Why you want show only the second image in your data base? this make any sense to you? 2 - Image rows in diferent row because you are spaning new TD everytime... when you should span multiple A inside the same TD, 3 - forloop never reachs 2 is because you dont have 2 3 values in your database... remind that starts from 0, so 0, 1, 2 is equal to 3 images... 4 - why you have one class called Hotel_Image and one attribute inside Hotel class called hotel_img? you must decide wich one you want to use, or tell me what you want to achieve with that

Comment: In general your logic is kinda confused, tell me what exacly you want o achieve and i'll change your code instead of just a better structure